# Adobe Brackets - Jump to code segment if live view area is clicked

Tags: html, css, editor, adobe-brackets

Is there any way to make brackets jump to the associated code if I click on a area in the live view? For example I want to see the the img-Tag of a picture if I click it in the live view.

Comment: This feature is proposed here:

https://trello.com/c/9IsdsBn3/564-jump-to-html-code-in-brackets-by-selecting-in-browser-live-development

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.  It looks like the link is just one way.